# Update To 13.04

Tags: 12.10

With Ubuntu 12.10 everything was perfect. A few days ago I upgraded to version 13.04 and only gives me problems.

With 13.04 I saved what I do after rebooting. For example, Firefox bookmarks disappear and I have to recreate them. Icons or programs that put in the left margin (favorite programs) also disappear when the computer restarts. All that I have saved in Downloads also disappears ...

I want to know if I can return to the version 12.10 or 12.04 , and what would be the easiest way to do this, because I don't have many computer skills. Thanks

Comment: How did you upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to impossible to downgrade.

I suggest you do a fresh install. Keep the fact that you upgraded in mind, and your problems might be due to a problem with a faulty upgrade and have nothing to do with 13.04.

Personally I would do a fresh install of 13.04. If you do not like 13.04, then do a fresh install of 12.04 or 12.10, your choice.

A fresh install should preserve your personal data in /home, but, I still advise you back up and data you do not want to loose just in case.